# Como cambiar la ruta que me redirige el middleware auth en Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

utilizando el metodo php artisan make:auth
Me encuentro con el problema que una vez que uso la proteccion de rutas haciendo

```
route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>'auth'], function(){...}
```

Cuando quiero ingresar a una ruta protegida, me redirige a /login pero yo tengo cambiada la ruta a login, por lo que me da el error

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Trate de hacer un seguimiento con el Go to.. y llegue a la clase Authenticate pero ahi me quedo y no encuentro el redireccionamiento a login para cambiarlo

Por lo que lei es distinto a los demas laravel 5. Supongo que tengo q modificar el handle() de RedirectIfAuthenticated

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/');
    }
        return $next($request);
}
```

probe retornando una vista si sale false del check pero ningun resultado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que es distinto en Laravel 5.3, ahora esa ruta se modifica en el **ExceptionHandler** :

app\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
/**
 * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }
    // ######### En esta línea cambias la ruta #########
    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

Comment: Habia encontrado una solucion provisoria, pero no me gustaba, apartir de tu comentario q borraste.  Arme un nuevo middleware con un handle similar a esta funcion, pero la verdad no la entendia  y ademas me quedaba sin las otras propiedades de 'auth'

Ahora como puedo manejar si se quiere acceder a una ruta inexistente, mandando una vista con un msj o algo asi?